# Lumen - MethodNotAllowedHttpException when passing data from form

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am new with laravel/lumen infrastructure. In my website using lumen, i am trying to have a contact form. I know there's a better way to handle email in lumen but since i dont know much with this framework i decided to have my own native php email sender functions and include it in my blade php template. Basically im just doing native php inside blade template. My form has a method of post and will redirect in the same page after they submit. When i tried it i got MethodNotAllowedHttpException error in RoutesRequests.php (line 596). Can anyone help me with this problem. (Let me know what info you needed to help me with this issue)

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your **code** and **what you have tried so far** so that we can help you debug your issue. Also take time to look at our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems like you didn't add a post route for the same URL as the GET request. Once you add that the error will go away and you can have a controller function to process the form data.

For email I think the best would be add a mail package like illuminate mail or something but thats entirely your wish as to how to implement that.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. I am really new to this framework. Can you help how to do the things that you've mention above? BTW, I am just using native php email sender functions and want to stick with that to avoid more confusion and trouble.

Comment: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing

I think it makes sense for you to do some reading up